# Conforming to protocol but nothing happens

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, delegates, protocols

I have 3 `UIViewControllers`. `ContainerVC` which contains 2 ContainerViews. First Container View is `DashboardVC` and second one is `SidebarVC`. The `DashboardVC` covers the entire screen, while the `SidebarVC` is outside.

I have a leading constraint for the `SidebarVC` that should be animated and the `SidebarVC` should slide in (from the left side). On the `DashboardVC` I have a `UIBarButtonItem` and when it's pressed it should perform the animation. The problem is that I'm doing something wrong with the delegate and when the `ContainerVC` conforms to the protocol, nothing happens.

PS: I have very hard time understanding protocols/delegates despite having watch a bunch of different videos on this concept. Here's the code:

**DashboardVC**

```
protocol SideBarDelegate {
    func showMenu()
    func hideMenu()
}

class DashboardVC: UIViewController {

    var delegate: SideBarDelegate?
    var isSideMenuOpen = true

    @IBAction func menuButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        if isSideMenuOpen {
            delegate?.showMenu()
            isSideMenuOpen = false
        }
        else {
            delegate?.hideMenu()
            isSideMenuOpen = true
        }
    }
}
```

**ContainerVC**

```
class ContainerVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var sideBarMenuLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
}

extension ContainerVC : SideBarDelegate {
    func showMenu() {
        sideBarMenuLeadingConstraint.constant = -290
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
    func hideMenu() {
        sideBarMenuLeadingConstraint.constant = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the calls of delegate. you will see its empty because you never assigned a value to the delegate. You do that the same way you add a value to a tableview.delegate property

Comment: Ugh, yeah, it does say it's nil. But I'm not quite sure how to do it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the delegate only on classes. To prevent memory leaks, do those two things:

Change:

```
protocol SideBarDelegate {
    func showMenu()
    func hideMenu()
}
```

to:

```
protocol SideBarDelegate: class {
    func showMenu()
    func hideMenu()
}
```

Now, rename delegate property to:

```
weak var delegate: SideBarDelegate?
```

Weak does not increase the reference counting. This is important to prevent memory leaks.

Your instance of ContainerVC must have some sort of reference to an instance of DashboardVC (or make the delegate static but I have never seen something like that). Then, in your viewDidLoad method of ContainterVC, set this:

```
myInstanceReferenceToDashboardVC.delegate = self
```

Comment: It did work with a static delegate. And I saw it in another answer as well. This was very helpful. Thank you